# Custom deserialization based on a class tag?

Tags: scala, serialization

I'm creating a client around an external key-value storage that returns bytes. Making a convenient `put` method is easy but I can't figure out how to create a convenient `get` method that has a generic parameter and returns a value of that type after applying custom deserialization. Something along the lines of:

```
val s = client.get[String]("string_key")
val x = client.get[Int]("int_key")

def get[T](key: String): T = {
  val b: Array[Byte] = storage.get(key)

  ??? match {
    case _: String => stringFromBytes(b)
    case _: Int => intFromBytes(b)
  }
}
```

Comment: You will usually solve this problem using **Typeclasses**. You can have an `Decoder[T]` trait, with a `def decode(bytes: Array[Byte]): T`, and finally `def get[T](key: String)(implicit decoder: Decoder[T]): T = decoder.decode(bytes = storage.get(key))`.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thanks, I always forget about typeclasses when I actually need them. And it's better than using `ClassTag` because compiler will catch errors when type arguments are derived to be `Nothing`.